# How to hide dates on Angular Calendar?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, calendar

I'm using Angular 12.0 Calendar and I want to hide the text that shows the day of the month on week view. I've dug through the code and tried looking online but can't find the location of what makes this text appear. I am talking about this one https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/kitchen-sink

not to be confused with material's.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFFLe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late, but today I needed the same thing and I came out with this.
Docs might be hard to read, but you can find that almost every component inside the Angular Calendar has a templateRef (check this out: https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/docs/components/CalendarWeekViewComponent.html#headerTemplate ).

```html
 <mwl-calendar-week-view [viewDate]="viewDate" [events]="events" 
            [hourSegmentTemplate]="weekViewHourSegmentTemplate" 
            [headerTemplate]="noDateHeaderTemplate"
            (eventTimesChanged)="eventTimesChanged($event)" (eventClicked)="eventClicked($event)">
        </mwl-calendar-week-view>
```

After that you need to set [headerTemplate] to a local ng-template. Personally I copied the default template hosted in the repo (you can find it here: https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar/blob/main/projects/angular-calendar/src/modules/week/calendar-week-view-header.component.ts